# Using mean of a set of data multiple time for different analysis

Tags: modeling, multiple-comparisons

I'm working with  drug A and its derivatives (7 derivatives of A). My hypothesis is that brain uptake of A derivatives is better than A. I'm using one-way ANOVA followed by Dunnett's test. Four of A derivatives however showed lower brain uptake than A so I proposed that they might be substrate for an efflux pump. So I run another set of brain uptake experiment with four of the A derivatives with an inhibitor.

I then did a statistics to compare the effect of brain uptake with and without efflux pump inhibitor, with brain uptake without inhibitor data were taken from the previous experiment.

However my advisor told me that it was statistically wrong to use a same set of data (in this case A derivatives without inhibitor) to do comparison.

I'm a bit confused by this since that means I need to do multiple sets of the same experiment to avoid re-using of the data?